# Border-color animation change javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie at javascript, and I have a challenge that I don't know where to start.

I need to develop a game similar to this [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAzLR.gif).

The goal is to click on the button an animation plays and then one of the prizes light up.

Anybody could help to kick start this with javascript/jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
José Miranda

Comment: change border Color: elementYouWantToChange.style.borderColor = yourColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something **like** :

**Note** : the explanation in code comment

**Update** : using css class instead of border color

```js
function runplay(){
 var winNumber = 4;//here you can set your ajax call 
     //or if use php to set the number like <? echo"var winNumber = 4;" ?>
 //return; //use if brwser error
 startplay(winNumber);

}
function startplay(winBoxNumber) {
 var loopcounts = 50;// all animation flash loop
 var selectfrom = 30;// end of random and select the wanted box
 var speed = 100;//animation speed 
 var mswitch = true;//true end with selected , false end with not selected
 var loops = 0;// dont change it
 var run = 1;// dont change it
 winBoxNumber -=1;//convert to real number becose array start from 0
 for (i = 0; i < loopcounts; i++) { 
  setTimeout(
    function(){
     if ($('.box:eq('+run+')').hasClass('random_box_selected')) $('.box:eq('+run+')').removeClass("random_box_selected");
     if ($('.box:eq('+winBoxNumber+')').hasClass('win_box_selected'))$('.box:eq('+winBoxNumber+')').removeClass("win_box_selected");
     if(loops > selectfrom){
       if(mswitch)$('.box:eq('+winBoxNumber+')').addClass("win_box_selected");
       mswitch = !mswitch;
   }else{
    run = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
       $('.box:eq('+run+')').addClass("random_box_selected");
   }
     loops+=1; 
    }
  , 100 * (i + i/2) );
 }
}
```

```css
.box{
 width: 24%;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
 height: 29%;
 margin: 0.5%;
 background-color: #7f7f7f;

}
.btn {
  border-radius: 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 3%;
}
.random_box_selected{
 border: 5px solid #b55200;
}
.win_box_selected{
 border-color:#aa0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="gobtn" onclick="runplay()">start</button>
<div style="width: 100%;height: 70%;position: absolute;">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>

<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>
<div class="box">8</div>

<div class="box">9</div>
<div class="box">10</div>
<div class="box">11</div>
<div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That if I want to change the border color via css class?
I tried chanching the variables, added the css classes and changed the if statement but nothing happend.

Comment: I've been strugling to change the border via css class. could you help me on this. I need to be able to set a css class because there will bee a request from the server that will tell me witch box is to be selected in the end of the animation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @José Miranda ok i got you , i will update the answer using "class"!

Comment: You the man Mohamed. Thanks a lot. I did learn a lot from your exemples.
Once again thnak you.