# Change color randomly on each item

Tags: javascript

I have this code, but insted of playing all items at the same time I want it to jump randomly through each item at a time.

At the end of this I want it to "blink" on one item.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
function randRange(data) {
      var newTime = data[Math.floor(data.length * Math.random())];
      return newTime;
    }

    function toggleSomething() {
      var timeArray = new Array(100, 500, 250, 650, 2000, 3000, 1000, 1500);
      $(".item").toggleClass("color_red");
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = setInterval(toggleSomething, randRange(timeArray));
    }
    
    var timer = setInterval(toggleSomething, 1000);
    // 1000 = Initial timer when the page is first loaded
```

```css
.item {
  color: #000;
}

.item.color_red {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Random Color list </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My list and target</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">One</li>
    <li class="item">Two</li>
    <li class="item">Three</li>
    <li class="item">Four</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice done!, you are learning fast ;check out the answer of your first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987191/border-color-animation-change-javascript), for this just use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) Selector to select one element from the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to ask for a level of caution, as flashing text isn't really considered that accessible and might cause some level of sensitivity to occur depending on speed.

As each `item` is an item in an array of `$(".items")` you can pick `$(items[0]).toggleClass("color_red")` to toggle the first item in the array.

If you set your `$(".items")` to a variable you can then count the number of items you have listed and perform a random pick.

I put the `removeClass` call to remove the class and allow you to set the class on a new element, and not double up.

this is the bit I added / changed:

```
var items = $(".item");
items.removeClass("color_red");
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(items).length);
$(items[rnd]).addClass("color_red");
```

**small edit, the 1 + would have meant it never pick the first item :)**

I didn't want to assume how many times you wanted to loop, but I think this gets you closer. when you know the number you want to flash on, just set that as the number in the array to pick each loop.

```js
function randRange(data) {
      var newTime = data[Math.floor(data.length * Math.random())];
      return newTime;
    }

    function toggleSomething() {
      var timeArray = new Array(100, 500, 250, 650, 2000, 3000, 1000, 1500);
      var items = $(".item");
      items.removeClass("color_red");
      var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(items).length);
      $(items[rnd]).toggleClass("color_red");
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = setInterval(toggleSomething, randRange(timeArray));
    }
    
    var timer = setInterval(toggleSomething, 1000);
    // 1000 = Initial timer when the page is first loaded
```

```css
.item {
  color: #000;
}

.item.color_red {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Random Color list </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My list and target</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">One</li>
    <li class="item">Two</li>
    <li class="item">Three</li>
    <li class="item">Four</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```