# Scroll to a anchor after a show/hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hit a wall on an issue I have.

This a continuation of [a question I already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989071/change-color-randomly-on-each-item) but with a new feature.

So far I have a button that when cliked it plays an animation (randomly changes the border-color), while it make a request to the server. The server then returns the result and hilights a specific item.

After that I used this function to hide a certain div and show another that gives the final result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".game_block").delay(8000).hide(500);
        $(".prize_block").delay(8000)
          .show(500)
          .queue(function () {
            $(this).addClass("showing");
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });
});
```

In addition to this I have to make an anchor so when the button is click it will jump to the top of the game block and plays the initianl animation that I just explained. 
At the end when the show/hide function comes to play and the final result is showed I whant it to auto scroll to the top of that div, so people can view the result.

Is there any may to achive this altering this fuction?

Comment: Yes. In fact, that's been discussed many, many times on SO. Perhaps you could do a search for "scrolling to an anchor in javascript"?

Comment: Maybe you want to get the callback function from `queue` so you know the animation is finished, then do the scroll?